# AJAX not working on updating DataGrid

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

This is my code:

```
<p:panel id="compPanelId" header="COMPUTERS" styleClass="compPanel">
<h:form id="availableCompForm">
    <div style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 8px;">
        <p:commandLink id="addCompBtn" value="Add" actionListener="#{coltsysLab.addComputer(event)}" style="height: 30px; font-size: 13px; margin-left: 10px;" update="availableCompForm"/>
    </div>

    <p:dataGrid id="availableComputers" value="#{coltsysLab.computer}" var="computer" columns="3" emptyMessage="No Computers Added Yet">  
        <p:column>  
            <p:graphicImage id="computer" value="http://localhost:8080/COLTSysResources/resources/images/#{computer.pic}" styleClass="computerImage"/>  
            <p:draggable for="computer" revert="true" scope="#{computer.status}" stack=".computerImage"/>
        </p:column> 

    </p:dataGrid> 

</h:form>
</p:panel>
```

Upon clicking Add command link, the datagrid does not update

Managed bean code in method addComputer is:

```
    try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection()) { 
         ColtsysDAO coltsysDAO = new ColtsysDAO(conn); 
         coltsysDAO.addComputer(currentComputer, labId); 
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace(System.err); 
     }
```

Comment: Can you show us method addComputer from yor Backing bean, and also tell us what is the scope of your bean. By the way, you cann say just `#{coltsysLab.addComputer}` instead `#{coltsysLab.addComputer(event)}`

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to make it work. The problem is that I am not updating the list of computers. I cleared the list `computers.clear()` first then, repopulated it again (after adding, it is directly added to the database so it's ok to clear it)